# Can't find the symbol addTextChangedListener

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am having issues with addTextChangedListener. I have 2 edittext (edittext1 and edittext2) that when the text (in this case numbers) are added or changed I need it to run a calculation and output it to a textview called resultstext.

I have found many examples and have modified them to do what I need them to do, but when I call the `editText1.addTextChangedListener.inputTextwatcher;` it tells me it cant find the symbol `addTextChangedListener`.  Below is the code, how to straighten this out?

```
package com.example.MyProject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.FocusFinder;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private android.widget.EditText editText1;
private android.widget.EditText editText2;
private android.widget.TextView resultsText;


private void onItemSelected() {
editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView13);
editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView15);
resultsText = (android.widget.TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView16);
}


  android.text.TextWatcher inputTextWatcher = new android.text.TextWatcher()

{
    public void afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable s) {
        calculateResult();
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
};

editText1.addTextChangedListener.inputTextWatcher;
editText2.addTextChangedListener.inputTextWatcher;

private void calculateResult() throws NumberFormatException {

    Editable editableValue1 = editText1.getText(),
            editableValue2 = editText2.getText();

    double value1 = 0.0,
            value2 = 0.0,
            result;

    if (editableValue1 != null)
        value1 = Double.parseDouble(editableValue1.toString());

    if (editableValue2 != null)
        value2 = Double.parseDouble(editableValue2.toString());

    result = ((0.5 * value1) / 6.1) * value2;


    resultsText.setText(String.valueOf(result));
}
}
```

Comment: Change `editText1.addTextChangedListener.inputTextWatcher;` to `editText1.addTextChangedListener(inputTextWatcher);`. Do the same for `editText2`.

Comment: thank you.  i made changes and same thing - cannot resolve symbol addTextChangedListener, but now also says unknown class when hover over (inputTextWatcher)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placement of some of your code was wrong. I have attempted to fix it. See if the following works for you:

```
package com.example.MyProject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.FocusFinder;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private android.widget.EditText editText1;
private android.widget.EditText editText2;
private android.widget.TextView resultsText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView13);
    editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView15);
    resultsText = (android.widget.TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView16);

    android.text.TextWatcher inputTextWatcher = new android.text.TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable s) {
            calculateResult();
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    };

    editText1.addTextChangedListener(inputTextWatcher);
    editText2.addTextChangedListener(inputTextWatcher);        
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}   

private void calculateResult() throws NumberFormatException {

    Editable editableValue1 = editText1.getText();
    Editable editableValue2 = editText2.getText();

    double value1 = 0.0,
            value2 = 0.0,
            result;

    if (editableValue1 != null)
        value1 = Double.parseDouble(editableValue1.toString());

    if (editableValue2 != null)
        value2 = Double.parseDouble(editableValue2.toString());

    result = ((0.5 * value1) / 6.1) * value2;


    resultsText.setText(String.valueOf(result));
}
}
```

Comment: thank you. that took care of the errors, but when i try to add a number in either of the edittext fields, the app crashes.

Comment: @user1232402 Can you post the updated code and Logcat output?

Comment: @user1232402 Also, change `if (editableValue1 != null)` to `if (editableValue1 != null && !editableValue1.toString().equals(""))`. Similarly, change `if (editableValue2 != null)` to `if (editableValue2 != null && !editableValue2.toString().equals(""))`.

Comment: thank you.  your fixes to my code worked great.  i added your last suggestion and everything came together.  I changed the final line to resultsText.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(result * 100.0) / 100.0)); and all is good and it rounds for me. 
thank you for your help and getting me on the right track

Comment: @user255882 - i had one final question for you.  i am not understanding why the "if (editableValue1 blah blah" change made the difference.  can you explain to me what was happening and how the change fixed it.  i am new to this stuff and really appreciate your help and the learning experience.

Comment: @user1232402 `if (editableValue1 != null && !editableValue1.toString().equals(""))` performs two checks. First check confirms that `editableValue1` object is not `null`. Second check confirms that editableValue1 is not holding an empty string. The reason for the second check becomes clear when we enter the `if-block`. If we don't perform the second check, when the following happens: `value1 = Double.parseDouble(editableValue1.toString());`, and if `editableValue1.toString()` is `""`, a `NumberFormatException` will be thrown because of `Double.parseDouble("")`.

Comment: @user1232402 To avoid this, we check against an empty string. The process doesn't stop here. You should include more checks in the `if-statement`. For example: try entering an alphabet, or a symbol, and your app will crash because, even though `editableValue1.toString()` isn't empty, `Double.parseDouble()` expects a number, not an alphabet. To avoid this, you can use regex to check that the input is indeed a number, and nothing else.

Comment: @user255882 - ok, i think i get it.  thank you for the explanation and advice.  i may play around with the regex. thank again for sharing your knowledge

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
           private TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        //your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
};
```

Then add watcher to your edittext

```
       youredittext.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```